# Android Data Backup - Does not work on applications installed by Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, backup

I have an Android application using the Data Backup service. After installing it using Eclipse on a device I can save some data and they become backed up well so far. I can also wipe the data and have them restored. This works as well. If I now take another device and install this application (again with Eclipse) like I'm going to switch the device, the restore process gets executed but don't deliver any data. (like there aren't any)

I'm asking me why. The package is the same, the google account too. Have I missed something in how data are mapped to apps?

Comment: Have you tried forcing backups/restores with the `bmgr` command? http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/bmgr.html

Comment: Yes. The answer was: "Unable to restore ...".